# How can I Load/Store Excel (XML) files into SQL Server tables (preserving all values, formatting, properties, formulas, etc)?

Tags: sql, xml, excel

Please forgive me if my question is too elementary, but I've been searching for an answer that  I haven't found yet, though I've had people give me pieces of the puzzle.  I want to load and store Excel files in SQL Server tables, populate some cells using stored procedures, and export them back out to Excel files when needed.

Since recent versions of Excel store data as XML and SQL Server can read/process XML, I think what I want to do is possible, but I haven't a clue how to do it.

Comment: You can get some idea of the XML structure of an Excel spreadsheet at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg278316.aspx As you will see, it is a ZIP archive containing multiple XML files which may complicate things for you

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to fire up an Excel object, suck in the spreadsheet file and then access the cells one by one, determining the cell value/format etc. This has a couple of drawbacks, namely you need Excel installed *(not so good on a server)*, and it is a big hammer to crack a nut.

Another option is to use the Excel database driver to read the spreadsheet like it was a database table. One of the large drawbacks with this is that, while it looks quite useful, it makes some big assumptions about the datatype of the columns in the spreadsheet. If for example, you have rows where the values in column A are dates, your imported table will have a column datatype of DateTime. If, after say 50 rows or so, you have something that cannot be a date, like "N/A" for example, your data table will get nulls for those cells *(because the driver has decided that column A looks like dates, so anything that isn't a date will become null)*. You get no warnings of this.

Another option, as alluded to in the comment on your original post, is to "read the XML in the spreadsheet". Well, this works fine, but assumes that a) the Excel file is an XML format one *(which old files wont be)* and b) you're happy to parse the XML which might change format. You could do worse than look at the OpenXML stuff for how to read a spreadsheet file from XML format, but if you have to handle xls files as well *(in addition to xlsx files)*, your best bet is probably to fire up an Excel object and use that.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the entire file in a BLOB field if you don't need to work with the file after it's loaded into the database. It would preserve all of the formatting and values as you suggest and would handle both the current and previous versions of Excel (making the XML format a non-issue).

Here's an article on MS.com that might help with this appraoch: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326502

Now, if you need to modify the values after you've saved the document within the database, you'll need to do something more like what @ross Watson describes above.

Comment: Sorry, didn't catch that you wanted to manipulate the values of the file within your application.